# How to Pro-gramatically add click Event to FrameworkElementFactory

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm trying to apply a data template programatically behind code. I've set the properties fine but I'm stuck on how to add the Click Event. May I ask how abouts do I do that?

Xaml Code that's being copied

```
<DataTemplate>
                <telerik:RadToggleButton Content="+" 
                                         Width="20" 
                                         Height="20" 
                                         HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"                                                         
                                         VerticalContentAlignment="Center"       
                                         Click="RiskButton_OnClick"
                                         Visibility="{Binding AttachmentVisibility, Mode=TwoWay, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}"/>
</DataTemplate>
```

What I currently have

```
var toggleButton = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(RadToggleButton));
toggleButton.SetValue(RadToggleButton.ContentProperty, "+");
toggleButton.SetValue(RadToggleButton.WidthProperty, 20.0);
toggleButton.SetValue(RadToggleButton.HeightProperty, 20.0);
toggleButton.SetValue(RadToggleButton.HorizontalContentAlignmentProperty, HorizontalAlignment.Center);
toggleButton.SetValue(RadToggleButton.VerticalAlignmentProperty, VerticalAlignment.Center);
//toggleButton.AddHandler(); <- what goes here?

DataTemplate dt = new DataTemplate
{
    VisualTree = toggleButton
};

dt.Seal();
```

Comment: Ed suggested different thing - AddHandler and not SetValue.

Comment: @Evk thnaks! i'm blind as a bat clearly LOL.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
toggleButton.AddHandler(RadToggleButton.ClickEvent, new RoutedEventHandler(SomeHandler));
```

SomeHandler is a RoutedEventHandler:

```
public void SomeHandler(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) 
{
}
```

Comment: Hi @Ed plunkett, thank you for your answer. I Just tried it out with a regular button as well and I get an error that  states `System.Windows.RoutedEvent` is not assignament to parameter type `System.Windows.DepencyProperty`